# Error: unexpected input in "reg1 <- lm(_"

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am pretty new to R, about 3 months in, and when I was trying to run a regression R shot me this error, Error: unexpected input in "reg1 <- lm(_"  the variable I use has an underscore, and some other variables too, I didn't know if R support underscore in a regression or not as thats the first time I had a variable with an underscore in it's name. If it doesn't, how can I change to name?

Comment: " I didn't know if R support underscore in a regression or not" -> At least not in this situation. Rule of thumb no numbers or special characters at the beginning of names! And: “it is a good idea to get into the habit of consistent and clear writing in any language, and R is no exception”. from here <https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/07/consistent-naming-conventions-in-r/>

Comment: For further reading: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#non-syntactic

Answer (score 0):

As good practice, always begin variable/column names with letters (although not explicitly the rule, and you can technically start with the period symbol, this will save hassle). When dealing with data imported into R with predefined column names (or just when dealing with dataframes in general) you can rename columns in the dataframe `df` as follows

```
names(df)[names(df) == 'OldName'] <- 'NewName'
```

Comment: Thank you! but the dataframe wasn't named by me!

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to, you can protect 'illegal' names with back-quotes (although I agree with other answers/comments that this is not good practice ...)

```r
dd <- data.frame(`_y`=rnorm(10), x = 1:10, check.names=FALSE)
names(dd)
## [1] "_y" "x" 
lm(`_y` ~ x, data = dd)
```